# Measure the difference in two lists

Tags: statistical-significance, measurement, order-statistics

Suppose that I have users reading 10 documents in some order they specify

```
 USER            READING_ORDER                       FINAL_ORDER
  1    [doc_user1_1, ..., doc_user1_10]  [doc_user1_3, ..., doc_user1_9]
  2    [doc_user2_1, ..., doc_user1_10]  [doc_user2_5, ..., doc_user2_3]
  3    [doc_user3_1, ..., doc_user1_10]  [doc_user3_8, ..., doc_user3_1]
  ...
```

where `reading_order` is the order they're going to read the 10 documents, and `final_order` is the order they made after reading all 10 documents. The `doc_useri_docid` field is a score (from 1 to 4) that they assign to the document.

Is there a way to measure the difference between two lists?

And is there a way to see if there's exists a pattern in the users' re-ordering? For example maybe docs with low score tend to be at the end of the list or vice-versa.